# Launch screen image not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, xcode

Working with the iOS launch screen and it's a very painful experience.

Finally got it to appear, but no matter what I do it won't align properly.  It's either stretched too far, or in a weird position off the screen.

What values for mode and stretching should I use to display this image viewer in my .xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `Launch Screen.xib` or `Launch Screen.storyboard`, you need to set the correct AutoLayout constraint in your IB file.

If you're not, you need to set the `Launch Images Source` in your project general settings page.

Comment: what if I want to set same for all like top,bottom,left,right all are set to 0 to superview in all screen sizes?